# Not allowing me to do each action more than once

Tags: javafx

I am having an issue with my code where whenever I try to do something more than once, the program will crash on me. For example, if I login, then log out and then log back in for a second time, the program will crash. This is happening for other things that I want to do more than once such as switching to another scene, going back to home then trying to go to the other scene again.

Will just post the code for the login part.

**Main**

```
package libraryapp;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.prefs.Preferences;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import libraryapp.model.Book;
import libraryapp.model.BookListWrapper;
import libraryapp.view.BrowseController;
import libraryapp.view.HomeOverviewController;
import libraryapp.view.LoginController;
import libraryapp.view.RootLayoutController;

public class LibraryApp extends Application {

private Stage primaryStage;
private BorderPane rootLayout;
/**
 * The data as an observable list of Books.
 */
private ObservableList<Book> bookData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public LibraryApp() {
    // Add some sample data
    bookData.add(new Book("Hans", "Muster"));
    bookData.add(new Book("Ruth", "Mueller"));
    bookData.add(new Book("Heinz", "Kurz"));
    bookData.add(new Book("Cornelia", "Meier"));
    bookData.add(new Book("Werner", "Meyer"));
    bookData.add(new Book("Lydia", "Kunz"));
    bookData.add(new Book("Anna", "Best"));
    bookData.add(new Book("Stefan", "Meier"));
    bookData.add(new Book("Martin", "Mueller"));
}

/**
 * Returns the data as an observable list of Books. 
 * @return
 */
public ObservableList<Book> getBookData() {
    return bookData;
}




@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    this.primaryStage.setTitle("LibraryApp"); 
    initRootLayout();
     showLogin();
}


/**
* Initializes the root layout and tries to load the last opened
* person file.
 */
public void initRootLayout() {
try {
    // Load root layout from fxml file.
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(LibraryApp.class.getResource("view/RootLayout.fxml"));
    rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();

    // Show the scene containing the root layout.
    Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);

    // Give the controller access to the main app.
    RootLayoutController controller = loader.getController();
    controller.setLibraryApp(this);

    primaryStage.show();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

// Try to load last opened person file.
File file = getBookFilePath();
if (file != null) {
    loadBookDataFromFile(file);
}
}





/**
 * Shows the home overview inside the root layout.
 */
public void showHomeOverview() {
    try {

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(LibraryApp.class.getResource("view/HomeOverview.fxml"));
        AnchorPane homeOverview = (AnchorPane) loader.load();



        // Set home overview into the center of root layout.
        rootLayout.setCenter(homeOverview);

    // Give the controller access to the main app.
    HomeOverviewController controller = loader.getController();
    controller.setLibraryApp(this);


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void showLogin() {
    try {

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(LibraryApp.class.getResource("view/Login.fxml"));
        AnchorPane login = (AnchorPane) loader.load();



        // Set home overview into the center of root layout.
        rootLayout.setCenter(login);

    // Give the controller access to the main app.
    LoginController controller = loader.getController();
    controller.setLibraryApp(this);


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void showBrowse() {
try {

    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setLocation(LibraryApp.class.getResource("view/Browse.fxml"));
    AnchorPane browse = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

    // Set browse into the center of root layout.
    rootLayout.setCenter(browse);

    // Give the controller access to the main app.
    BrowseController controller = loader.getController();
    controller.setLibraryApp(this);

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}


/**
 * Returns the main stage.
 * @return
 */
public Stage getPrimaryStage() {
    return primaryStage;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(args);
}
```

**Login Controller**

```
package libraryapp.view;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import libraryapp.LibraryApp;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

/**
* FXML Controller class
*
* @author Michael
*/
public class LoginController implements Initializable {

/**
 * Initializes the controller class.
 */

    @FXML
private AnchorPane loginPane;



@FXML
private Label lblMessage;  
@FXML
private TextField txtUsername;
@FXML
private PasswordField txtPassword;

private LibraryApp libraryApp;


public String getString(String tagName) throws SAXException, IOException,     ParserConfigurationException{
    File file = new File("src/libraryapp/account.xml");
    DocumentBuilderFactory docBuildFactory =   DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuildFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = docBuilder.parse(file);

    NodeList list = document.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
    if (list != null && list.getLength() > 0){
        NodeList subList = list.item(0).getChildNodes();

        if (subList != null && subList.getLength() > 0) {
            return subList.item(0).getNodeValue();
        }
    }
        return null;
   }

@FXML
private void login(ActionEvent event) throws IOException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException {


     String email = getString("email");

     String password = getString("password");


    if (txtUsername.getText().equals(email) && txtPassword.getText().equals(password)){

        libraryApp.showHomeOverview();
    } else{
        lblMessage.setText("Username or password invalid!");
    }


}

    @FXML
private void register(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

   AnchorPane pane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Register.fxml"));
   loginPane.getChildren().setAll(pane);
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
}    

 public void setLibraryApp(LibraryApp libraryApp) {
    this.libraryApp = libraryApp;
}

}
```

And this is the error that I get

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
... 52 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at libraryapp.view.LoginController.login(LoginController.java:82)
... 62 more
```

**Logout**

```
@FXML
public void logout(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

        File bookFile = libraryApp.getBookFilePath();
        libraryApp.saveBookDataToFile(bookFile);


    AnchorPane pane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Login.fxml"));
    browsePane.getChildren().setAll(pane);
}
```

Comment: Which variable is null?

Comment: It's pointing to this `libraryApp.showHomeOverview();`

Comment: So `libraryApp` is null. You probably need to show how you are implementing the log out functionality.

Comment: When you call logout, you never call `setLibraryApp()` on the new controller. So `libraryApp` is null in that controller...

Comment: Updated original post to include it at the bottom. I should note that it isn't just the login. If i navigate from the Home scene to the browse scene which displays a list of books then navigate back to home, then try to go back to the browse scene, I get the same issue. Just displayed the login part as I assume it will be the same issue for the other parts.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, that is it working.

Changed the logout to:

    @FXML
    public void logout(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        libraryApp.showLogin();
        
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation of `logout()` loads the login fxml file again, but does not set the `libraryApp` field on the new controller. Consequently, that field is null in that instance of the controller, and you get a null pointer exception.

Since you already have a reference to the `libraryApp`, you can reuse the existing code to load the login screen simply by calling

```
libraryApp.showLogin();
```